# Is it possible to implement OOP in this case?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am making a simple website that displays products stored in the database.
There are a few categories and each category has a few products under it.
I was thinking about making a class for each product type and then display it on the page.

Example database table:

```
product_id |     name     |   category  |  color  | quantity
    1      |    apple     |    fruits   |  green  |   10
    2      |    potat     |  vegetables |  brown  |   3
    3      |  strawberry  |    fruits   |   red   |   7
```

Now I fetch only the fruits and I want to display them on the website, with an option to modify/delete them from the page later if needed.

Does it make sense to use OOP in this case?

I want to be able to update the information using an object. Or create a new type of product. For example changing stock quantity for an object:

```
//SQL query to fetch all fruits here
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['quantity'];
}
```

The problem is that when I fetched all the objects, I did not store them in a variable, so there is no way to declare "`$apple=new Fruit()`" for example, so I can't use OOP, although it really looks like a good idea to use OOP here so that I can implement methods such as quantity updating methods:
`$apple->set_quantity(20);` when a user wants to update the number of apples he has.

Is there still some way to use OOP here?

Comment: It always makes sense to use OOP, by virtue of your database being relational (i.e. having a table of rows with shared columns) is in itself proof that you probably SHOULD use OOP. As with Jeroen's answer, you can create a class constructor to instantiate your `Fruit` (or `Apple` that extends `Fruit`) for every row you iterate over.

Answer (score 3):

In (PHP) applications using a database to *manage state* it's common practice to *map* an object *class* to your database table in order to interact with its data in an OOP manner.

So for your table you would implement a `Product` class for your *product* table such as:

```php
class Product
{
    private int $id;

    private string $name;

    private string $category;

    private string $color;

    private int $quantity;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name, string $category, string $color, int $quantity)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getCategory(): string
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function getColor(): string
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }
    
    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): void
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }
}
```

Then you will commonly query the `Product` objects using queries like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = "fruits"
```

Which allow your to *hydrate* these `Product` objects using the query results:

```php
$products = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $category = $row['category'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $products[] = new Product($id, $name, $category, $color, $quantity);
}
```

The resulting `Product` objects "represent" your database data from an OOP point of view:

```php
$product->setQuantity(123);
$product->getQuantity(); // 123
```

You would still have to implement means to *persist* `Product` objects back to your database however!

Comment: You can also use `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)` to have PDO do this mapping automatically.

Comment: is there a typo in the last part of the code? shouldn't it be something like `$product[1]->setQuantity(123)`? because `$product` was never declared

Comment: What's the point in creating intermediate variables. You can just use `fetchAll` without the loop

Comment: @Dharman but how? You wanna store each in the property. Also, I was also talking about set methods: They should include way to store back to DB no? not just "set"

Comment: @pileup Like this: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_CLASS

Comment: Definitely look into [Doctrine ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/getting-started.html) for mapping relational objects and databases, they handle all the instantiations etc. for you - Very powerful